# How do I check that every file in folder A exists in folder B?

Tags: linux, backup, fdupes

I'm reorganizing some files on my harddrive and have an old copy of a folder, what I want to do is to ensure that every file in folder A (the old copy) exists in folder B. Each folder contains at least 200 files, most of which are likely duplicates.

Caveat: I can't just check the filenames, I must also ensure that they have the same content (à la `fdupes`).

I checked the manpage for `fdupes` if there was some way to do the inverse operation (i.e. figure out which files *don't* have any copies) but came up empty handed, even if the functionality would exist I still have files that exist only in folder B.

These two questions were similar but were Windows only so not much help:

- [How can I find all folders in Folder A that does not exist in Folder B?](https://superuser.com/questions/237467/how-can-i-find-all-folders-in-folder-a-that-does-not-exist-in-folder-b)
- [Delete files from one folder if a similarly named file does not exist in another folder](https://superuser.com/questions/482821/delete-files-from-one-folder-if-a-similarly-named-file-does-not-exist-in-another)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have `fdupes` installed. Does it produce a list of duplicate files?

Comment: @choroba Yes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a list of duplicate files, just compare it to the list of all files to find the single ones:

```
fdupes -r dir1 dir2 | grep -vwFf- <(find dir1 dir2 -type f)
```

- `-w` only mathces whole words (not substrings, so file `abcd` doesn't get matched by `abc`)
- `-F` consideres the patterns to be literal, not regular expressions
- `-f` uses the specified file (`-` in this case, i.e. standard input) as a list of expressions to match against.
- `-v` as you probably know, shows the nonmatching lines.

This should output a list contains the files only found in one of the folders, it should be easy to verify that they are all in folder B by skimming or grepping for the name of folder A (below called `dir1`) like this:

```
fdupes -r dir1 dir2 | grep -vwFf- <(find dir1 dir2 -type f) | grep -F dir1
```

Comment: Worked wonders, just had to add the `-r` flag to `fdupes`, edited the post so that it recurses. Thanks!

Comment: Using duplicate scanners will generally not work as well as using `rsync -rcnv` for this. The options specify recursion (follow subdirectories), verify files by checksum rather than name/date, "dry run" (don't actually do anything), and verbose (show detailed results). Filter out directories by piping to `| grep -v '/$'` and you should not see any of your files listed in the output if everything is identical between directories. [jdupes](https://github.com/jbruchon/jdupes) has a `-I/--isolate` option for situations like this, but it doesn't currently work.